# Simple HTML single password form

Tags: html, forms, helper, form-helpers

I will preface this question with, I am a newbie so go easy on me.

I am trying to create simple html form with a single password field.

What I like to happen is when you type in a password it take me you a website by the same name.

Example: you type in monkey, it would take you to monkey.html.

It sounds super easy but I am lost.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Go easy on yourself and start by reading [help] and [mcve]. We want to see effort and CODE. That said, the form would give a 404 on a wrong password. `<form onsubmit="location=this.password.value+'.html'; return false"><input type="password" name="password" /></form>`

Comment: It's very hard to help based on this question other than writing the whole thing for you, and that's not really what this site is for. What part of the form do you not know how to do? The HTML? Detecting form submission? Pulling the password from the form? Redirecting the page? If you don't know how to do any of that, perhaps you should start with a basic tutorial to build up your skills.

Comment: Why not just ask for the website to go to? e.g. 'monkey'. Why are you concerned about 'hiding' the website as a password? What happens when the 'password' is changed? Does it go to a different website?

Comment: @JJJ thank you for responding. I know html code to create the form, I just don't know how to get the action completed once you hit submit. So that would be taking the imputed text then redirecting you to the website with the same text.

Comment: @RyanVincent - that is his problem. It is a quite effective simple way of hiding a site from spidering and it's security by obscurity. Like to keep your little sister from looking at the site you made for your football friends

Comment: @RyanVincent privacy, I would like to just like to limit who sees the info.

Comment: @mplungjan that's a good way to put it. I'm sure if someone wanted to see it, I don't care if you see it. I just want to a little barrier.

Comment: @mplungjan, that makes sense - easy to do and 'private' enough for a small group - neat :)

Comment: I have tried to up vote both but it won't work since I am a newbie. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a duplicate so here is a form would give a 404 on a wrong password.

```
<form onsubmit="location=this.password.value+'.html'; return false">
  <input type="password" name="password" />
</form>
```

The return false is to stop the form from submitting.
I use inline JS because the issue is so simple it is not worth rolling out the unobtrusive script with e.preventDefault and all.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta try to put some efforts. Write some code by yourself and then ask for help, not spoonfeed. As you're new to StackOverflow, I'll just help you out this time, but please make sure that next time you put in considerable amount of efforts before posting a question without any code.

Here you go:

```
<input type="password" id="test"/>
<input type="button" onclick="window.open('https://google.com/'+document.getElementById('test').value+'.html');" value="Button"/>
```